# Update all objects in nested array with values from other collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of vehicles with the following car structure:

```
 {
    "_id": {}
    brand : ""
    model : ""
    year : ""
    suppliers : [
        "name": "",
        "contact": ""
        "supplierId":"",
        "orders":[], <-- Specific to the vehicles collection
        "info":"" <-- Specific to the vehicles collection
    ]
    
 }
```

And a Suppliers collection with a structure like:

```
{
    "name":"",
    "contact":"",
    "_id":{}
    "internalId":"",
    "address":"",
    ...
}
```

I need to add a new field in the suppliers array within each document in the vehicles collection with the internalId field from the supplier in the suppliers collection that has the same _id.

if the supplier array has a document with the id 123, i should go to the suppliers collection and look for the supplier with the id 123 and retrieve the internalId. afterwards should create the field in the supplier array with that value.

So that i end up with the vehicles collection as:

```
 {
        "_id": {}
        brand : ""
        model : ""
        year : ""
        suppliers : [
            "name": "",
            "contact": ""
            "supplierId":""
            "internalId":"" <-- the new field
        ]
        
     }
```

Tried:

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
    {
     "$unwind": { "path": "$suppliers", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false }
    },
    { 
       "$project": { "supplierObjId": { "$toObjectId": "$suppliers.supplierId" } } 
    },
    {
     "$lookup":
        {
         "from": "suppliers",
         "localField": "supplierObjId",
         "foreignField": "_id",
         "as": "supplierInfo"
        }
    },{
     "$set": {
    "suppliers.internalId": "$supplierInfo.internalid"
  }}
     
])
```

But it is adding the new field, to the returned values instead to the array item at the collection.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it is adding the new field, to the returned values instead to the array item at the collection.

The `.aggregate` method does not update documents, but it will just format the result documents,

You have to use 2 queries, first aggregate and second update,

I am not sure i guess you want to execute this query for one time, so i am suggesting a query you can execute in mongo shell,

1. **Aggregation query:**

- `$lookup` with pipeline, pass `suppliers.supplierId` in `let`
- `$toString` to convert object id to string type
- `$match` the `$in` condition
- `$project` to show required fields
- `$map` to iterate loop of `suppliers` array
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `suppliers_data` array and find the matching record by `supplierId`
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object properties with new property `internalId`

2. **Loop the result from aggregate query using `forEach`**
3. **Update Query to update suppliers array**

```
db.vehicles.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "suppliers",
      let: { supplierId: "$suppliers.supplierId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [{ $toString: "$_id" }, "$$supplierId"]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            supplierId: { $toString: "$_id" },
            internalId: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "suppliers_data"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      suppliers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$suppliers",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$s",
              {
                internalId: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$suppliers_data",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$this.supplierId", "$$s.supplierId"] },
                        "$$this.internalId",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
.forEach(function(doc) {
    db.vehicles.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { suppliers: doc.suppliers } });
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cs2y6p9dP5w) for aggregation query, and [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0L_Okl1RK_6) for update query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one way to solve this is by using `$addFields` and `$lookup`. We first flatten any matching suppliers, then add the property, then regroup.

You can find a [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j2XJtMz0dhd) via Mongo Playground.

### Database

Consider the following database structure:

```js
[{
  // Collection
  "vehicles": [ 
    {
      "_id": "1",
      brand: "ford",
      model: "explorer",
      year: "1999",
      suppliers: [
        {
          name: "supplier1",
          contact: "john doe",
          supplierId: "001"
        },
        {
          name: "supplier2",
          contact: "jane doez",
          supplierId: "002"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "2",
      brand: "honda",
      model: "accord",
      year: "2002",
      suppliers: [
        {
          name: "supplier1",
          contact: "john doe",
          supplierId: "001"
        },
        
      ]
    }
  ],
  // Collection
  "suppliers": [
    {
      "name": "supplier1",
      "contact": "john doe",
      "_id": "001",
      "internalId": "999-001",
      "address": "111 main street"
    },
    {
      "name": "supplier2",
      "contact": "jane doez",
      "_id": "002",
      "internalId": "999-002",
      "address": "222 north street"
    },
    {
      "name": "ignored_supplier",
      "contact": "doesnt matter",
      "_id": "xxxxxxx",
      "internalId": "xxxxxxx",
      "address": "0987 midtown"
    }
  ]
}]
```

### Query

This is the query that I was able to get working. I'm not sure how efficient it is, or if it can be improved, but this seemed to do the trick:

```js
db.vehicles.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$suppliers"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "suppliers",
      localField: "suppliers.supplierId",
      foreignField: "_id",  // <---- OR MATCH WHATEVER FIELD YOU WANT
      as: "vehicle_suppliers"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$vehicle_suppliers"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "suppliers.internalId": "$vehicle_suppliers.internalId"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      brand: {
        $first: "$brand"
      },
      model: {
        $first: "$model"
      },
      year: {
        $first: "$year"
      },
      suppliers: {
        $push: "$suppliers"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

### Results

Which returns:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "brand": "honda",
    "model": "accord",
    "suppliers": [
      {
        "contact": "john doe",
        "internalId": "999-001",
        "name": "supplier1",
        "supplierId": "001"
      }
    ],
    "year": "2002"
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "brand": "ford",
    "model": "explorer",
    "suppliers": [
      {
        "contact": "john doe",
        "internalId": "999-001",
        "name": "supplier1",
        "supplierId": "001"
      },
      {
        "contact": "jane doez",
        "internalId": "999-002",
        "name": "supplier2",
        "supplierId": "002"
      }
    ],
    "year": "1999"
  }
]
```

Comment: It returns the desired set, but how can i add the internalId field to the actual collection and not just to the returned set?

Comment: That is a little more tricky and would require knowledge of the programming language you are working with. I do not know of a way that allows for `$lookup` inside of `updateMany`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#std-label-update-many-update those are the only aggregate pipeline stages allowed in updateMany.